# category_url_title randomly parsing in channel:entries tag

Tags: categories, channel

I am trying to generate a link by parsing the category_url_title in a channel entries tag. However the link will randomly parse with the category in it and sometimes it will not. I am at a loss as to why it gets parsed this way. Here is the code:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" limit="3" category="4|5" orderby="random" dynamic="no" disable="category_fields|member_data|pagination"}        

<p><a href="{exp:transcribe:uri path="/products/{categories limit="2"}{category_url_title}{/categories}/{url_title}"}">link here</a></p>

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

So sometimes the link gets parsed like this:

```
http://website.com/template/category_url_title/entry
```

and sometimes like this:

```
http://website.com/template/entry
```

Can anybody sheet some light on this, if familiar?
Thanks :-).

Comment: Do all of your product entries have at least one category assigned to them?

Comment: It's required to assign a category to each entry through a plugin to avoid entries not having a category.